# Create an APK for Android from a kivy/python program

Tags: android, python, kivy

How can I create an APK for Android, on *Windows*, from a kivy & python program?

I cannot seem to find a suitable, easy-to-understand tutorial.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The build tools do not run directly on windows right now.

You have a couple of options:

1) Use a linux virtual machine. Kivy provides a prebuilt VM image with python-for-android ready to use, as described at http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android.html#testdrive .

2) Use the cloud builder at http://android.kivy.org/ . There will hopefully be tools to access this more flexibly with buildozer in the nearish future.

Comment: Thanks. What do I put for "package"?

Comment: It should be a backwards pseudo-url like java packages seem to use. Something like `org.test.yourpackagename` is fine.

Comment: Which virtual machine host do you recommend on Windows? Hyper-V is installed on Windows 10 once Visual Studio 2015 is installed. But its Linux guest interop is clumsy.

@rtharper There are other made-for-android APK templates in 2015, like Xamarin, or Apache Cordova, but either the C# Android API or node.JS would have to begin execution of the Python-Kivy app.